# AWS Lambda function randomly start blocking my requests due to CORS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which has the response structure like so:

```
const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...summonerData }),
    };
```

As you can see, I am allowing CORS and it works fine. But sometimes, it just randomly starts blocking the requests. And I don't do anything to fix it, it just starts working after some time.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On our project, we had a CORS error from time to time when executing lambdas. It happens that when you have an error inside your lambda function, it will throw a CORS error on the frontend. Try to check what error happens inside your lambdas when it stops working, probably a wrong parameter for your call.

Comment: You're right. I realized whenever my API calls threw an error, I was getting CORS.